# ESP8266 "ovf" when doing small double maths

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm using a Wemos D1 based on the ESP8266 wifi chip with the Arduino C framework to do some simple small math.
As far as I can gather, double precision is available so I'm using it - with a maximum of something like 1.8*10^103.
But I'm getting an ovf when I try to calculate a number around 5*10^8.
Any ideas please?

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  Serial.println("Hit any key to start math");
  double te = 6800;
  double res = te * te;
  Serial.println(res);
  te = 68000;
  res = te * te;
  Serial.println(res);
   te = 680000;
   res = te * te;
  Serial.println(res);
}

void loop(){
}
```

Prints

```
46240000.00
ovf
ovf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino does supports 4-byte double data type. and your code is indeed produced a valid double value that is not overflow (ovf).

The problem that you see has to do with the way Arduino implement `Serial.print()` function which is almost like a half-cooked hack to support floating-point and is not as reliable as [vprintf()](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1) that is available in avr-libc. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L223) which print `ovf` for anything bigger than 4294967040.0 or smaller than -4294967040.0. I thought that ESP8266 Arduino Core has fixed this instead of inheriting the ugly implementation of Arduino `Serial.print()`, but apparently not.

Luckily the ESP8266 Arduino Core does have a `Serial.printf()` method that provide better floating point rendering. This code will shows that your number is indeed a valid number for double data type.

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);

  double te = 68000;
  double res = te * te;
  Serial.println(res);  //this will produce 'ovf'
  Serial.printf("Result=%f\n", res);  //this will produce correct 4624000000.000000
}
```

Please noted that `Serial.printf()` is ESP8266 specific implementation to support  full floating point `vprintf()` in the standard library. It is not available for standard Arduino Boards.

For Arduino boards, there is a way to use `sprintf()` which inherits from `vprintf()` to print the correct floating point with some twist on linker options during code compilation process. I have a blog post [Do you know Arduino - sprintf() and floating point](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/01/do-you-know-arduino-sprintf-and-floating-point/) talk about how to do that.

Comment: Brill, thanks for the insightful answer! I'm actually doing some more machine learning (SVM) maths in the background that might be overflowing but debugging it is the first step - Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! But Serial.printf is not available for Arduino. What can I do for Arduino, please?